# Ember Inspector Config not defined error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to build the sample application, i'm getting this error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: EMBER_INSPECTOR_CONFIG is not defined`, Can someone tell me how to define EMBER_INSPECTOR_CONFIG ??

This is my index.html fle

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ember.js • TodoMVC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
        <section id="todoapp">
          <header id="header">
        <h1>todos</h1>
        <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
          </header>

          <section id="main">
        <ul id="todo-list">
          <li class="completed">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>Learn Ember.js</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>...</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>Profit!</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
          </section>

          <footer id="footer">
        <span id="todo-count">
          <strong>2</strong> todos left
        </span>
        <ul id="filters">
          <li>
            <a href="all" class="selected">All</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="active">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="completed">Completed</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <button id="clear-completed">
          Clear completed (1)
        </button>
          </footer>
        </section>

        <footer id="info">
          <p>Double-click to edit a todo</p>
        </footer>
     </script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>
    <script src="js/router.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update December 24 2014:**

The Ember Inspector has been updated.  If you encounter this issue you're likely still using an old version for some reason.

---

This is a bug in the Ember Inspector that has been fixed [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/commit/9b343aa9827dd31ba417279a266438d66d5b90bf) (but not yet released).

It should not affect your application, and only shows up if the Ember Inspector is active and the content script is delayed.

You can either ignore the error when it happens and wait for the next Ember Inspector version to be released (which is soon), or set `window.EMBER_INSPECTOR_CONFIG = null` temporarily.